# angular2 systemjs.config with many package that recalls to one path open only last and need it component

Tags: angular, systemjs

My systemjs.config has two package home and manuallyCheck - this two diferrent ng2 module that add in file home.ts and manually_check.ts

```
    (function (global) {
    System.config({
        defaultJSExtensions: true,
        paths: {
            'npm:': './node_modules/'
        },
        map: {
            home: './app',
            manuallyCheck: './app',
            // angular bundles
        },
        packages: {
            manuallyCheck: {
                main: './manually_check.js',
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            },
            home: {
                main: './home.js',
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            },
        }
    });
})(this);
```

and in two html file I include it with it selectors

```
<script src="./systemjs.config.js"></script>
<script>
    System.import('home').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
</script>
<home>Loading AppComponent content here ...</home>

<script src="./systemjs.config.js"></script>
<script>
    System.import('manuallyCheck').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
</script>
<manually-check>Loading AppComponent content here ...</manually-ckeck>
```

and have error

```
EXCEPTION: Error in :0:0 caused by: The selector "home" did not match any elements
```

when I add two different systemjs.config.js where include only one pakage all OK